# Dependencies in kotlin not working on groovy files

Tags: android, gradle, kotlin

I've tried to add **buildSrc** to my Android project for creating kotlin class for having all versions and dependencies.

[image: Kotlin Versions file]

It does works on Android Studio 3.2.1  but it does not work on android 3.3.

configuration AS 3.2.1:

- kotlin 1.3.11
- gradle 5.1 & 3.2.1

(w¡orks)

configuration AS 3.3

- kotlin 1.3.11
- gradle 5.1 & 3.2.1

(not working) only works if I migrate build.gradle file to build.gradle.kts

any suggestions?

Edited:

[image: build.gradle.kts]

Comment: Can you show your `buildSrc/build.gradle.kts` file

Comment: I've just added it

Comment: Only thing I can spot is that you're missing "import org.gradle.kotlin.dsl.`kotlin-dsl`" at top of that file

Comment: I've added it and it says 'packages cannot be imported' Indeed, I've been able to add kotlin class to build.gradle file without it.

Answer (score 0):

I've found the issue. Android Studio 3.3.0 has a problem with Gradle files dealing with Kotlin. I have to install again AS 3.2.1